# Subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ given by $X_{1} = (0,1)\cup (3,4)$ and $X_{2} = (0,1)\cup (1,2)$. Is $X_{1}$ homeomorphic to $X_{2}$?

Tags: general-topology

"Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be subspaces of $\mathbb R$ given by $X_1=(0,1)\cup(3,4)$ and $X_2=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$.

Is $X_1$ homeomorphic to $X_2$?"

I think we can easily find a homeomorphism by defining a piecewise function from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$ and $(3,4)$ to $(1,2)$ where both functions are just lines. Would that be the right approach?

Comment: Yes, that idea works fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  so $X_1$ is homeomorphic to $X_2$, but $\mathbb R\setminus X_1$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R\setminus X_2$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Yes, that’s right.